# Are all linear maps injective on non-null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume you have finite dimensional spaces $V$ and $W$. Let $v \in V$. Can you define a linear map that takes 2 different vectors $u$ and $v$ $(u \neq v)$ and maps them to the same non-zero $w \in W$? My initial thinking is no because linear maps are injective on the non-null space by the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps?

Answer (score 0):

If $u=\lambda v$ for some scalar $\lambda$, then the answer is negative, because if $f(v)=w\ne0$, then$$f(u)=f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)=\lambda w\ne w,$$since $\lambda\ne1$ (otherwise, $u=v$), and $w\ne0$. The same argument applies if $v=\lambda u$ for some scalar $\lambda$.

Otherwise, the answer is affirmative. Then $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent. Consider a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $V$ with $v_1=u$ and $v_2=v$ and consider the linear map $f\colon V\longrightarrow W$ such that $f(v_k)=w$ for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, and also the non-null space is not a subspace.

I'm assuming the fundamental theorem of linear maps means the rank-nullity theorem, which I'll restate for reference:

**Rank-nullity theorem**: let $f\colon U\to V$ be a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces, where $\dim(U)=n$ and $\dim(V)=m$. Then $\dim(\operatorname{ker}(f))+\dim(\operatorname{im}(f))=n$. Some people call $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ the *null space* of $f$ and refer to $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f))$ as the *rank* of $f$ (or the rank of some matrix representing $f$).

In particular this implies that $f$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{ker}(f)=0$. Proof: suppose $f$ is injective $f(x)=0$. Since $f(0)=0$, we must have $x=0$. Now suppose $\operatorname{ker}(f)=0$ and $f(x)=f(y)$. Linearity implies $f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)=0$, so $x-y=0$. Thus $x=y$, so $f$ is injective.

Let $F_0$ be the null space of $f$ — that is, the set of all $x\in U$ such that $f(x)=0$. Also let $F_{\neq 0}$ be the "non-null space" of $f$, defined as the set of all $x\in U$ for which $f(x)\neq 0$. As sets, $F_{\neq 0}$ is just the complement of $F_0$.

Now $F_0$ is an actual subspace of $U$, but $F_{\neq 0}$ is not. Probably the most apparent reason is that $F_{\neq 0}$ doesn't contain $0$ (since $0\in F_0$). But it's worse than this — even if you just declare that $0$ be in $F_{\neq 0}$, the set $F_{\neq 0}$ will almost never form a vector space. A useful example to consider is the linear map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ which projects onto the $x$-axis. This would be represented by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
The null space is just the $y$-axis, and the "non-null space" consists of everything else. Here $F_{\neq 0}$ here looks like the whole plane $\Bbb R^2$ with just one line missing. This is not a vector space since it's not even closed under addition: $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are not sent to zero, but $(1,1)+(-1,1)=(0,2)$ is in the null space. Moving past this issue, it's still not true that $f$ is injective on $F_{\neq 0}$. For example, $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are both sent to $1$.

All this said, your intuition is somewhat correct! But you need to redefine what you mean by "non-null space." Instead of just deleting the null space from $U$, you want to take what we call the *quotient* of $U$ *by* the null space. This quotient space $U/F_0$ consists of vectors in $U$ "up to" vectors in the null space. I.e., two vectors in $F_{\neq 0}$ are considered the same if they differ by something in $F_0$. Formally, an element of $U/F_0$ isn't actually a vector in $U$, but rather a collection of many vectors. In general, it's true that $f$ induces an injection $U/F_0\to V$. This is sometimes referred to as the first isomorphism theorem, and you probably won't encounter it until you take an abstract algebra class.

Comment: What about some of the answers above? They seem to contradict that thinking?

Comment: @DarbyBond Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the projection $\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ sending $(x_1,…,x_n)$ to $x_1$. Then *all* vectors with the same first entry will be mapped to the same vector, which gives a counterexample to your claim.

So *all* vectors with a first component of zero are mapped to the zero vector. In particular all linear multiples of a chosen vector $(0,x_2,…,x_n)$ are sent to zero. This shows that linear maps are in general not even injective on one-dimensional subspaces.

An analogous example can be realized with any abstract vector spaces $V,W$ by means of fixing some basis $\{v_1,…,v_n\}$ and constructing a linear map sending $v_1$ to some nonzero $w\in W$ and all other $v_i$ to 0.

Now if you have two prescribed distinct vectors $v$ and $v‘$ and wonder whether there is a linear map sending both to the same nonzero $w\in W$ the answer is: it depends. If $v$ and $v‘$ are linear independent (which in this case just means *are not a multiple of each other*) then it is perfectly possible, by extending $\{v,v‘\}$ to a basis of $V$ and defining a linear map by sending both $v$ and $v‘$ to the same $w$, while sending all other basis vectors to 0. However if $v$ and $v‘$ are linear **not** linear Independent (meaning $v‘ = \lambda v$ for some scalar $0\neq \lambda \neq 1$), then it is impossible to map both of them to the same nonzero $w$. This is because in this situation for any linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$ we have
$$f(v)= w\implies f(v’)=f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v) = \lambda w \neq w$$

Comment: But is your projection a linear map if $x_1 \neq 0$?

Comment: I am defining a map, so $(x_1,…,x_n)$ is supposed to denote an *arbitrary* vector. The map is the projection onto the first component, which definitely *is* a linear map. To be even more clear: I want to say that eg. (2,0) maps to 2, while (-1,3) maps to -1. I hope that clarifies things a bit.